# Return length of border segment between geographic areas in geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I am new to using `geopandas` so I have a fairly basic question. I want to identify how much border **contact** happens between neighboring places in a geo-dataframe.

I will provide an example. The following code reads in a pre-loaded geoframe, randomly creates countries marked as "Treated", defines a function that gives their neighboring countries, and then graphs the result with the countries that border having a slightly lighter shade.

```
import geopandas as gp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
path = gp.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
earth = gp.read_file(path)
africa = earth[earth.continent=='Africa']
africa['some_places'] = np.random.randint(0,2,size=africa.shape[0])*2

# Define and apply a function that determines which countries touch which others
def touches(x):
    result = 0
    if x in africa.loc[africa.some_places==2,'geometry']:
        result = 2
    else:
        for y in africa.loc[africa.some_places==2,'geometry']:
            if y.touches(x) :
                result = 1
                break
            else:
                continue
    return result
africa['touch'] = africa.geometry.apply(touches)

# Plot the main places which are 2, the ones that touch which are 1, and the non-touching 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
africa.plot(column='touch', cmap='Blues', linewidth=0.5, ax=ax, edgecolor='.2')
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

For me this gave the following map:

[image: Map of Africa with Treated and Border Countries]

Now the problem is that actually I don't want to indiscriminately shade all areas light blue. I -- ideally -- want to determine the **length** of border along treated countries and then have a sliding scale of how affected you are based on how much border you share with one or more treated countries.

At the very least, I want to be able to throw away places that only share like 1 or 2 miles of border with another country (or maybe meet at a corner). Any advice or solutions welcome!

Comment: Intersection of two neighbouring polygons will give you shapely Linestring representing shared boundary, from which you can then get the length. Something along these lines `state1.intersection(state2).length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need an example that demonstrates proper geospatial operations to get the result. My code below show how to do `intersection` between N and S America continents, get the line of intersection, then, compute its length. And, finally, plot the line on the map. I hope it is useful and adaptable to your project.

```
import geopandas
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make use of the provided world dataset
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# drop some areas (they crash my program)
world = world[(world.name != "Antarctica") & (world.name != "Fr. S. Antarctic Lands")]

# create a geodataframe `wg`, taking a few columns of data
wg = world[['continent', 'geometry', 'pop_est']]
# create a geodataframe `continents`, as a result of dissolving countries into continents
continents = wg.dissolve(by='continent')

# epsg:3857, Spherical Mercator
# reproject to `Spherical Mercator` projection
continents3857 = continents.to_crs(epsg='3857')

# get the geometry of the places of interest
namerica = continents3857.geometry[3]   # north-america
samerica = continents3857.geometry[5]   # south-america

# get intersection between N and S America continents
na_intersect_sa = namerica.intersection(samerica)   # got multi-line

# show the length of the result (multi-line object)
blength = na_intersect_sa.length   # unit is meters on Spherical Mercator
print("Length in meters:", "%d" % blength)

# The output:
# Length in meters: 225030

ax = continents3857.plot(column="pop_est", cmap="Accent", figsize=(8,5))

for ea in na_intersect_sa.__geo_interface__['coordinates']:
    #print(ea)
    ax.plot(np.array(ea)[:,0], np.array(ea)[:,1], linewidth=3, color="red")

ax.set_xlim(-9500000,-7900000)
ax.set_ylim(700000, 1400000)

xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()

rect = plt.Rectangle((xmin,ymin), xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin, facecolor="lightblue", zorder=-10)
ax.add_artist(rect)

plt.show()   # sometimes not needed
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: Definitely useful. I ended up being able to use `intersection` splendidly. Can you explain a bit more what you are doing with `crs` portion? I get that you need to get it out of whatever lat-long projection that it is in to get the proper distance; however, it is unclear to me why you do that so early and not on some `length` of the intersection. For example, can you call `x.intersection(y).length.to_crs()`?

Comment: @LucasH:  The method `.to_crs()` belongs to `geoDataFrame` such as `world`, `wg`, and `continents`, it is not available to `namerica`, `samerica`, and `na_intersect_sa ` which are not `geoDataFrame`.

Comment: @LucasH: The property `.length` that yields linear distance of the line objects has the same units as of the `CRS` in use. Hence, it is in `degrees` as the `world` data is in un-projected lat-long (equivalent with epsg:4326 CRS). I reproject CRS to epsg:3857 to get the unit `meters` from the line's length property.

Comment: One important thing is that the length obtained with `.length` in this example can be very wrong if the line objects fall in the highly distorted areas of the map projection. The most accurate method is to compute the (geodetic) distances from the series of coordinates of the vertices along the lines.